# Error in running R script in cmd window

Tags: r, dll

I have a bat file that I have run successfully for some time from the command line, which calls R and then an R script. It has failed lately, and it feels like it has something to do with package loading. I have R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) and RStudio Version 0.99.489.

The errors occur apparently as packages are being loaded, but they are not R errors, but rather errors looking for a variety of .dll's, ending in an 0x7e error. Not sure why R/Windows is looking for dll's (?!).

I also tried to google the "LoadLibraryFromPath" function, but got nowhere.

Here is the cmd window output:

```
Warning message:
package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.1.3
Warning message:
package 'scales' was built under R version 3.1.3
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: 'zoo'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Warning message:
package 'rkt' was built under R version 3.1.2
Loading required package: methods
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\system\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\oci.dll is not found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\oci.dll is not f
ound, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\TIBCO\splus82\oci.dll is not
found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll found
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\system\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error:
0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\SQLLib80.dll is
not found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Program Files (x86)\TIBCO\splus82\SQLLib80.dll is
 not found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\SQLLib80.dll is n
ot found, error: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\system32\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error
: 0x7e
LoadLibraryFromPath: FQ Dll C:\Windows\SQLLib80.dll is not found, error: 0x7e
.
.
.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, it was caused by windows update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126587

Although it is not a good solution and I don't recommend it, uninstallation of this update solves the problem.

As described in workaround of the update, reinstallation of oracle should solve it as well, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I tired the MS workarounds, but had no luck--removing the patch as you suggested cleared up the issue. I'm hoping that the KB 3147071 @Tony metioned will fix the patch

Answer (score 3):

I have been debugging this problem for a customer when I found this post. Now after working with the Microsoft product team I can confirm the issue you have described has been addressed and is now expected to be released through KB 3147071 on 4/12/16. Be on the lookout!