# ODBC error running R script in cmd window

Tags: r, odbc

This is a follow-up question to:
[Error in running R script in cmd window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875911/error-in-running-r-script-in-cmd-window)

I am still getting errors, but I switched from 64bit to 32bit R, and I think I am closer now, so I was hoping the following would jog someone's memory or tinfoil :)

Anyway, the paradox is that the following code runs instantly *INSIDE* of R :

`library(RODBC)
    myconn <- odbcConnect("****", uid = "*******", pwd = "*******") 
    test <- sqlQuery(myconn, "select * from tableAXd")
    close(myconn)
    summary(test)`

But the very same code (in bat_test.R), sourced from a .bat file with this code:

```
C:\Users\********\Documents\R\R-3.3.1\bin\Rscript.exe  "C:\schedule\bat_test.R"
```

generates the following error in the cmd window:

[RODBC] ERROR: state IM104, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and the Application...

So, why would the exact same code run sweetly from R, but choke on ODBC from a .bat file?

Thanks for listening...
isotope

Comment: What database are you connecting to?

Comment: Oracle 10i if I'm not mistaken, is that what you are looking for? I pixelled out all of the info I could get fired for revealing :)

Comment: Is that the only line in .bat file? What happens if you run that one line in CMD prompt or PowerShell?

Comment: I ran it in cmd window directly, and got *exactly* same error :( Good idea tho. Sorry, I'm not familiar with PowerShell. And yes, that's all that's in the .bat file, outside of a PAUSE command to keep the window up.

Comment: Parfait, Just tried the .bat with and without lib.loc=. Either way it recognized RODBC fine (with the warning that RODBC was built under 3.3.2).  I also thought that since I'm running 3.3.1, the 3.3.2 build of RODBC might be a problem, but as I said the code runs fine from inside R.  Super ideas tho, exactly the kind of error logic testing I'm not really good at.

Comment: Actually ignore that last item. On the drive over, I realized you do read in library  fine. Are you connecting with Oracle DSN or driver? If you don't know, show first arg of `odbcConnect()` which should not reveal anything private. And what do you mean *in R*? R studio? R gui? R.exe? Very strange that same script fails but not in these environments. Try running in new R session.

Comment: First arg is the name of our main schema, which I put in the "User Data Sources" name field of the ODBC Data Source Admin dialog and linked to a "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver. By "in R", I mean within RStudio, right in the command window. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks